# How can I compute the kinetic energy of a mass tied to a wall and sliding down a slope?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I've come across an exercise and I'm having some issues understanding how the kinetic energy is computed.

[image: Exercise Picture]

Both the masses are sliding without friction and I'm required to find their kinetic energy in order to solve the exercise.

The system consists of a wedge of mass $ m $ which is free to slide on a horizontal plane without friction. A block of mass $m $, connected to an ideal rope which passes over an ideal pulley, is sliding on the wedge. The other end of the string is attached to the wall.

The wedge can therefore move in the horizontal direction and the block can only slide along its side. The constant angle $ \theta $ is a given parameter. The string can be assumed horizontal before the wedge and parallel to the slope afterwards.

In the solution of the exercise, the kinetic energy of the wedge is found to be $ K_1 = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{q}^2 $. The kinetic energy of the block is specified to be

$$
K_2 = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{q}^2 \left( 2 - 2\cos\theta \right)
$$

I'm having trouble understanding where the $ \left( 2 - 2\cos\theta \right) $ factor comes from. Intuitively, I would have thought that the speed of the two masses would be the same and that it would be $ \dot{q} $.

Thank you for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kinetic energy of the sliding wedge is definitively:
$$K_1 = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{q}^2$$

For the mass on the incline, things are more involved because the velocity of the mass relative to the ground is the composed velocity of the incline relative to the ground and the velocity of the sliding mass relative to the incline.

$$ \overrightarrow{V} _{m/ground}=\overrightarrow{V} _{wedge/ground}+\overrightarrow{V} _{m/wedge}=\dot{q} \overrightarrow{i}   -\dot{q} \big(cos( \theta )\overrightarrow{i}-sin( \theta )\overrightarrow{j}\big) $$

So you get for the kinetic energy:
$$K_2 = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{q}^2 \big( \big(1-cos( \theta )\big)^2 +sin( \theta )^2\big) =\frac{1}{2} m \dot{q}^2 \big(2-2~cos( \theta )\big)$$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have added a short description to the post.

Comment: The two masses are the objects labelled with $m$. The string is tied to the wall and the block. The weight of the block pushes the incline to the left, allowing the block to descend.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks!